# Updating zoom behavior from v3 to v5

Tags: d3.js, charts, zooming

The problem i am facing is that i am not able to write the function following in my code because of version mismatch.
Code is

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
.x(x)
.y(y)
.scaleExtent([1, 10])
.on("zoom", zoomed);
```

I have tried by this way

```
  const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 4])
  .x(this.xScale)
  .on('zoom', () => {})
```

But it does not work for me.

How to write same function in d3 version 5? I want to make line chart scrollable in x axis with y axis as fixed position using d3 version 5

This is my implementation Basic Code

```
    private createLineChart() {
    this.width = 2000 - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = 600 - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

// X AXIS
this.xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(this.dataset[0].fluencyData.map((data) => {
    return new Date(data.date);
  }))
  .range([0, this.width]);

// Y AXIS
this.yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 110])
  .range([this.height, 0]);

// Line Generator
this.line = d3.line()
  .x((data) => this.xScale(new Date(data.date)))
  .y((data) => this.yScale(data.wcpm));
// .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

// Add SVG to Div
this.svg = d3.select('#displayChart').append('svg')
  .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
  .attr(
    'viewBox',
    '0 0 ' +
    (this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right) +
    ' ' +
    (this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom))
  // .attr('width', this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
  // .attr('height', this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')');

// Define the div for the tooltip
this.toolTipDiv = d3.select('#displayChart').append('div')
  .attr('class', 'tooltip')
  .style('opacity', 0);

// Append XAXIS to the SVG
this.svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'xAxis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + this.height + ')')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(this.xScale).tickSizeOuter(0).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %d')));

const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 4])
  .extent([100, 100], [this.width - 100, this.height - 100])
  .x(this.xScale)
  .on('zoom', () => {
    console.log(d3.event.transform);
    // this.svg.select('#displayChart').attr('d', this.line);
  });
this.svg.call(zoom);

// Append YAXIS to SVG
this.svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'yAxis')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(this.yScale).tickSize(-this.width)
  );

// Make a Path for Dataset
this.svg.append('path')
  .datum(this.dataset[0].fluencyData)
  .attr('class', 'line')
  .attr('d', this.line)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',0)');

// Text Heading of DATE in chart
this.svg.append('text')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (-20) + ',' + (this.height + 13) + ')')
  .attr('dy', '.35em')
  .attr('class', ' xAxis')
  .text('Date');
 }
 }
```

Error I am getting is

```
LineChartComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: d3__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.zoom(...).scaleExtent(...).x is not a function
    at LineChartComponent.push../src/app/line-chart/line-chart.component.ts
```

Comment: Could you provide your full code of what you are trying to implement. It is very difficult to predict what is the error you are seeing etc. If possible create a Block (www.blockbuilder.org) or a fiddle (www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I have added Code in the question in which I have made a function for creating Line Chart. I am not getting what to do exactly in this code for making x axis only scrollable in chart

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With d3v3 and before, the zoom could track a scale's state. From the documentation, `scale.x()`: "Specifies an x-scale whose domain should be automatically adjusted when zooming." ([docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Zoom-Behavior.md#x)). This modifies the original scale.

D3v4+ does not have zoom.x or zoom.y methods.

With d3v4+, the zoom does not track or modifiy a d3 scale's state. Infact, for d3v4+, the zoom behavior doesn't even track the current zoom state: "Zoom behaviors no longer store the active zoom transform (i.e., the visible region; the scale and translate) internally. The zoom transform is now stored on any elements to which the zoom behavior has been applied.([change log](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#zooming-d3-zoom))".

As part of this, and more importantly, "Zoom behaviors are no longer dependent on scales, but you can use transform.rescaleX, transform.rescaleY, transform.invertX or transform.invertY to transform a scale’s domain([change log](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#zooming-d3-zoom))".

So rather than have the zoom update the d3 scale, we need to do this ourselves. The most common way this is done is through a reference scale, which remains unchanged, and a scale to which we apply the zoom transform:

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .on("zoom",zoomed)

var x = d3.scaleLinear()....   // working scale
var x2 = x.copy(); // reference scale.

function zoomed() {
  x = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x2) // update the working scale.
  // do something...
}
```

So, something like this:

```js
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0,1])
  .range([0,500]);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
.x(x)
.scaleExtent([1, 10])
.on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .call(zoom);
  
var axis = d3.svg.axis()
   .orient("bottom")
   .scale(x);
  
var axisG = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,30)")
    .call(axis);
  
function zoomed() {
   axisG.call(axis);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="500" height="200"></svg>
```

Becomes something like that:

```js
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,1])
  .range([0,500]);
var x2 = x.copy(); // reference.

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 10])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .call(zoom);
  
var axis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x)
  
var axisG = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,30)")
    .call(axis);
  
function zoomed() {
   x = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x2)
   axis.scale(x);
   axisG.call(axis);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="500" height="200"></svg>
```

*Note that d3.event.transform.rescaleX is for continuous scales - you have an ordinal band scale, so we'll need to use a slightly modified approach for band and/or point scales:*

```js
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(10).map(function(d) { return d/10; }))
  .range([0,500]);
var x2 = x.copy(); // reference.

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 10])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .call(zoom);
  
var axis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x)
  
var axisG = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,30)")
    .call(axis);
  
function zoomed() {
   // Rescale the range of x using the reference range of x2.
   x.range(x2.range().map(function(d) {
     return d3.event.transform.applyX(d);
   }))
   axisG.call(axis);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="500" height="200"></svg>
```

*This is band/point scale solution is based on [this issue](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/134) and Bostock's proposed solution to it*

Comment: Thank you for your response But I am still getiing error like                                  
 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'transform' of null...   this is error is at line     
 x = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x2) can you please help me to solve this?

Comment: Is this line within the zoomed function? The error appears to be suggesting that there is no event to pull a transform from.

Comment: Yes line is in the zoomed funciton .                                                                      const zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 10]).on('zoom', () => {
        this.xScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(this.xScaleCopy);
      });   It is like if I am using scaleLinear() in x axis then it is working but I am using Date in x axis then this error is appearing in your code also and in my code also.

Comment: In my code instead of scaleLinear() I have used                                          
     `this.xScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(this.dataset[0].fluencyData.map((data) => {
        return new Date(data.date);
      }))
      .range([0, this.width]);
    this.xScaleCopy = this.xScale.copy();`

Comment: Ah, yes, ordinal scales can't be rescaled like this, there is no v5 out of the box solution, though you can see this problem and the solution proposed by Mike Bostock [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/134). The solution here is fairly basic, I'm not on the computer at the moment, but I will update the answer when I am back at the desk with the option for an ordinal scale that follows the same pattern as the linear scale.

Comment: My apologies for not seeing that you had a band scale right away, will update the answer shortly.

Comment: Updated with an example that follows the same pattern as the continuous scales.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190807/discussion-between-jd-hirapara-and-andrew-reid).